# C++ Question,error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++

Would you please help me with this simple code in C++, I don't know what is the problem here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace::std;
template <class Type>
Type binsearch (Type item,Type *table,Type n)
{
    int bot=0;
    int top=n-1;
    int mid, cmp;
    while (bot<= top)
    {
        mid=(bot+top)/2;
        if(item==table(mid))
            return (mid);
        else if (item <table[mid])
            top=mid-1;
        else
            bot=mid+1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main ()
{

    int nums[]={10, 12, 30, 38, 52, 100};
    cout<< binsearch(52, nums, 6);
}
```

Comment: post at least what the error is and where it appears

Comment: @NAIEM: I recommend that you start learning how to process the information from the error messages. The compiler probably told you what exact line the problem was in, and that should have limited the search. If you still cannot understand what happens in that line, post a question, but don't forget to provide the full information that the compiler is giving you (i.e. line number) (add a comment to the line that the error is reported: `// compiler error here` or the like)

Answer (score 1):

That `table(mid)` was supposed to be `table[mid]`

Answer (score 1):

It has to be 
    `if(item==table[mid])`

not

```
if(item==table(mid))
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are confusing the `[` and `(`. Instead of

```
---
mid=(bot+top)/2;
if(item==table(mid))
    return (mid);
---
```

you need

```
+++
mid=(bot+top)/2;
if(item==table[mid])
    return (mid);
+++
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(item==table(mid))
```

should be

```
if(item==table[mid]) //notice square brackets []
              ^   ^
```